# Python: operator "+="

Tags: python, operators

I do not understand an operator in the code below

```
for i in range(m):
    c += a[i] * b[i]
return c
```

What is the meaning of `c += a*b` in python?

Comment: `c = c + a[i] * b[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

`c += a*b` means `c = c + a*b`